# JQuery slideToggle timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide, slidetoggle

I have simple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

          $("button").click(function() {
              $("div").slideToggle("slow");
          });

      });
  </script>

  <style>
  div { width:400px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Toggle</button>
  <div style="border: 1px solid">

    This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You
    should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
    your life.  Congratulations!
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to hide the div panel automaticaly after 10 seconds if my mouse cursor isn't over the panel.
How can I do it (change the code above) to implement that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/XRYLk/3/

I added mouseleave so in case the mouse was over it when first function fires up, it will set timer on mouseleave.

**jQuery:**

```
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("div").slideToggle("slow");
    });

setTimeout(hidepanel, 4000);

function hidepanel(){
    if($('div').is(':hover') === false){ $('div').slideToggle(); }
}

 $('div').mouseleave(function(){ setTimeout(hidepanel, 4000); });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
 if($('.to_hide').css("display") == "block")
{
    $(".to_hide").mouseout(function(){

        setTimeout(hidepara,10000);
    })
}
function hidepara()

    { $(".to_hide").hide();

}
```

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/kaYLG/

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple solution. Idea is, if you don't move your mouse over the div-container.. it will [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) the container itself in 2000ms (I put 2000ms, because its boring to wait [10sec](http://www.google.com/search?q=10%20seconds%20to%20milliseconds)).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <style>
        div {width: 400px; border: 1px solid;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in your life. Congratulations!
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var mouseover_to = setTimeout(function () {
                $("div").slideUp("slow");
            }, 2000); // Change it to 10000 to be 10sec
            $('div').mouseover(function () {
                clearTimeout(mouseover_to);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/dZdCt/) ]**</sup>

1. First it will wait till the document is ready
2. It will start the countdown to 2000ms with `setTimeout()` and sets it as resource to `mouseover_to` variable.
3. However, if [`mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) is detected over the `div` then the countdown will be canceled with `clearTimeout()`, thanks to the help of the resource `mouseover_to`