# JQuery show/hide panel on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery slideToggle timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528503/jquery-slidetoggle-timeout)

I have simple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

          $("div").hide();

          $("button").hover(function() {
              $("div").slideDown("slow");
          });

          setTimeout(hidepanel, 4000);

          function hidepanel() {
              if ($('div').is(':hover') === false) {
                  $('div').slideUp(); 
              }
          }

          $('div').mouseleave(function() { setTimeout(hidepanel, 4000); });
          $('button').mouseleave(function() { setTimeout(hidepanel, 4000); });
      });
  </script>

  <style>
  div { width:400px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Toggle</button>
  <div style="border: 1px solid">

    This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You
    should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
    your life.  Congratulations!
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need:

1. Show the panel (div) while mouse cursor is over the button or over the panel (div)
2. Hide panel when mouse is not over button or panel for 4 seconds
3. Hide panel immediately when I click on the page on any place outside the panel or button.

What should I change im my code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why cant you just ask it all at once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528503/

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Why not just use an existing jQuery plug-in like clueTip?

Comment: Kalle H. Väravas - I'm sorry but different questions and different solutions

Answer (score -2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/AWM44/4/

Obviously, you'll want to be more specific with the selectors than "DIV" and "button" but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/TQp9C/1/

The interesting part is hiding the panel when clicking outside of the panel/button.

```
$(document).click(function (e) {    
    if (e.target.id !== "btn" && e.target.id !== 'panel' && $(e.target).parents('#panel').length === 0)
    {
       hidepanel(); 
    }
});
```